# Internal potential energy of a system of particles in Goldstein, p.10-11

Tags: classical-mechanics

This question is a follow-up of [question 129793](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129793/a-confusion-about-notation-in-goldstein), "A confusion about notation in Goldstein". My question is the same as asked in the comment by Anatoly Vorobey to the answer by Emilio Pisanty.

On page 10-11 of the second edition of Classical Mechanics, 1980, Goldstein deduces the internal potential energy of a system of particles. We have $ V_{ij}= V_{ij}(|r_i-r_j|) $, so this potential is a function of 6 variables (3+3 coordinates). I interpret $ \nabla_i $ as

$ \nabla_i V_{ij} = \left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_i},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z_i} \right) V_{ij} $

where $ x_i, y_i, z_i $ are the coordinates of $ r_i $, the location vector of particle i.

$ \nabla_{ij} $ I would interpret, according to Goldstein's hints, as

$ \nabla_{ij} V_{ij} = \left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{i-j}}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_{i-j}},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z_{i-j}} \right) V_{ij} $

where $x_{i-j}, y_{i-j}, z_{i-j}$ are the coordinates of the difference vector $ r_i - r_j = r_{ij}$. Is this correct?

What I don't understand at all is Goldstein's statement that

$ \nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij} V_{ij} $,

which is used in his following deductions. Thanks for help!

Comment: $x_{i-j},y_{i-j},z_{i-j}$ are just variables in the derivative, their orientation is in the same direction as $x,y,z$ and are in the same space. So these variables don't make a difference in derivative. They re just linearly related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing around with the problem some more, I think I found the answer.

Let's assume for a simple example that

$ V_{ij}(|r_i-r_j|)= \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2+(z_i-z_j)^2}$.

Our potential depends on 6 variables, so we can take 6 different partial derivatives. Therefore, $\nabla_i V_{ij}$ can be different from $\nabla_j V_{ij}$, in fact we have $\nabla_i V_{ij}=-\nabla_j V_{ij}$. But what is $\nabla_{ij} V_{ij}$? We could rewrite

$V_{ij}=\sqrt{(x_{i-j})^2+(y_{i-j})^2+(z_{i-j})^2}$,

which now represents a function of only 3 variables. Then, according to our above interpretation, $\nabla_{ij} V_{ij}$ is the gradient of $V_{ij}$ with respect to these 3 variables.

And this suddenly makes it clear: $x_{i-j}=x_i-x_j$ is itself a function of $x_i$, so according to the chain rule we have

$\dfrac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial x_i} = \dfrac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial x_{i-j}} \dfrac{\partial x_{i-j}}{\partial x_i} $

with the second factor on the right hand side being equal to one. So it naturally follows that

$\nabla_i V_{ij}=\nabla_{ij} V_{ij}=-\nabla_j V_{ij}$.